# How can I make iTerm2 *cd* into a directory by clicking on *ls* results?

Tags: terminal, bash, shortcut, iterm

Would it be possible to make some sort of remap where **command-clicking** or **highlighting** some text in the terminal triggers iTerm2 to attempt to `cd <text>`? Would make life somewhat easier when navigating around complex directory trees with long names.

I found [these instructions](https://coderwall.com/p/b7e82q/quickly-open-files-in-iterm-with-cmd-click) for making **command-click** trigger an action on the clicked filename or word. But after trying the `Run command...` option with `cd \1` (for "cd to this clicked item"), that doesn't seem to work.

---

The answer below evidently **does not work on remote logins**; if anyone has a solution that does so, I will accept your answer.

Comment: cd <kbd>Tab</kbd> will list the directories in the current directory - note this is the shell not iTem2/Terminal that does this

Comment: Oh I know; but Tab completion often would be slower than being able to click `ls` results, especially if you have many directories with very similar names (which might require you to hit Tab multiple times before a single directory is isolated, or just type out the full name).

Comment: (I do modelling for my work, and often have lots of nested directory trees with long and very similar names, that are a pain in the butt to cd into even with tab completion.)

Comment: You can make Path Finder (and I think Finder) open a terminal in the directory selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that you need to go `Preferences` -> `Profiles` -> `Advanced` -> `Semantic History` and use `Run coprocess...` and `echo cd \1` to get the desired result.

Don't ask me why this works or how I found this solution.

[image]

Comment: Damn... doesn't work on remote logins, I guess the `coprocess` is local then.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Maybe this isn't possible then.

Comment: I came up with an approach (see answer below) that uses a Paste from Selection keyboard shortcut. Perhaps this is the best we can do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach that should work in remote sessions. Just create the keyboard remap as shown below (go to iTerm2...Preferences...Keys and click on the "Plus" sign, then select "Paste from Selection..." from the drop-down menu for "Action"). Take note of the Replace...With fields.

This way, we can **double click** on an item to highlight it and **press the magic keyboard shortcut**. We've now `cd`'d into a directory without having to type out its name.

[image]

It would be possible to do this with a **Pointer** action instead of a keyboard shortcut, but unfortunately, the Pointer section does not have the same detailed options for "Paste from Selection". Perhaps this will change in a future release.

Comment: I would prefer this solution, since it works on remote sessions. Who's the wizard now? :D

Comment: Thanks :) but it is a bit hacky. Hope they expand the Cmd+Click options in a future version.